# How to download attachments from JIRA v6.3.15 in java

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to get list of JIRA issues created after a given date and download the respective attachment files from my application in java. The JIRA Server version I am currently using is 6.3.15.

When I searched on web I found the below REST client, however it says it supports till JIRA Server 6.0. I want to know whether it supports 6.3.15 as well, if not are there any other alternate solutions?

REST Java Client for JIRA
by Atlassian Labs for JIRA Server 5.0 - 6.0

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.jira-rest-java-client

Answer (score 5, accepted):

REST Java Client for JIRA is a wrapper around JIRA REST https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/6.3.15/.
I see that there was no changes in attachment REST methods between 6.0 and 6.3.15. Take the current version and I am sure it will work for you.

Another way is to directly use JIRA REST API and in your case it can be even simpler. I guess you need:

- call https://YOUR_JIRA/rest/api/2/issue/CURRENT-ISSUE?fields=attachment for one issue or 
  https://YOUR_JIRA/rest/api/2/search?jql=YOUR_JQL&fields=attachment to return set of issues matching JQL query (make sure to take care about paging if you expect more than 1000 issues)

For each issue there will be a section with attachments:

```
        "attachment": 
    [
      {
        "self": "https://vkrupach.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/attachment/10100",
        "id": "10100",
        "filename": "to test",
        "author": 
        {
          "self": "https://vkrupach.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?username=vkrupach",
          "name": "vkrupach",
          "key": "vkrupach",
          "emailAddress": "vkrupach@ukr.net",
          "avatarUrls": 
          {
            "48x48": "https://vkrupach.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10122",
            "24x24": "https://vkrupach.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=10122",
            "16x16": "https://vkrupach.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10122",
            "32x32": "https://vkrupach.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=10122"
          },

          "displayName": "Volodymyr Krupach [Administrator]",
          "active": true,
          "timeZone": "Europe/Moscow"
        },

        "created": "2015-04-19T10:05:59.696+0300",
        "size": 469,
        "mimeType": "text/html",
        "content": "https://vkrupach.atlassian.net/secure/attachment/10100/to+test"
      }
    ]
```

- "content": is direct link to file.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. When I tried the mentioned url for an issue it does return the issue information, however the attachment section is missing.
Do we need to explicitly enable the attachments? How to enable them? will there be any security issues?

_{"expand":"renderedFields,names,schema,transitions,operations,editmeta,changelog","id":"69685","self":"http://HOST/rest/api/2/issue/69685","key":"DCE-2402"}_

Comment: For me it returns attachments. Is your REST authenticated?

Comment: I have tried it in another tab of chrome where I have already login to JIRA. It did not ask for authentication. As per my under standing from the below comment, the attachment field should be default enabled. I am not sure where can I enable it, as I don't have admin privileges.                                                                                                                 _"The 'Attachments' field must be available in the "default screen". Otherwise the attachments will not be included to the response (although they are visible when viewing the issue in the browser...)"_

Comment: It looks like we can enable the required fields at this URL http://localhost:8080/secure/admin/ViewIssueFields.jspa

Comment: how to directly save the file to classpath from content field in java? I tried with InputStream but it throwing error